# Experienced an error #1060 - Duplicate of Column 'forum_enabled'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1060

What is wrong with this?

```
ALTER TABLE `groups`
ADD COLUMN `forum_enabled`  enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE 
latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `admindeco`;

ALTER TABLE `user_badges`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `user_id, badge_id`;

ALTER TABLE `furniture`
ADD COLUMN`behaviour_data`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER 
`interaction_type`;

ALTER TABLE `users`
MODIFY COLUMN `rank_vip`  int(1) NULL DEFAULT 1 AFTER `rank`;

ALTER TABLE `server_settings`
CHANGE COLUMN `variable` `key`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE 
latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'server.variable' FIRST ;

    ALTER TABLE `catalog_deals`
    DROP COLUMN `page_id`,
    DROP COLUMN `cost_credits`,
    DROP COLUMN `cost_pixels`,
    MODIFY COLUMN `items`  text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE 
    latin1_swedish_ci 
    NOT NULL AFTER `id`,
    ADD COLUMN `room_id`  int(11) NOT NULL AFTER `name`;

    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

I am getting following error:

> SQL query: ALTER TABLE groups ADD COLUMN forum_enabled ENUM( '0', '1' ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER admindeco ; MySQL said: Documentation #1060 - Duplicate column name 'forum_enabled'

Comment: Are you saying you don't have a column forum_enabled in groups before you issue the alter statement?

Comment: @P.Salmon Hi, thanks for your reply, that's correct!

Comment: Is that the exact error message? And can you add the output of show create table groups

Comment: This is the exact message: SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `groups` ADD COLUMN  `forum_enabled` ENUM(  '0',  '1' ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' AFTER  `admindeco` ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1060 - Duplicate column name 'forum_enabled'

Comment: @Livetolearn it seems there'e already a column called `forum_enabled` in `groups` table

Comment: @P.Salmon Apologies, are you able to advise how I can go about outputting the table groups?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes it seems to be the error here yet I can't find the duplicate despite running through the entire SQL...

Comment: show create table groups ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems like the column you are trying to add in the first statement already exists in the table.

A simple solution is to DROP the column before you add it, like :

```
ALTER TABLE `groups` 
DROP COLUMN `forum_enabled`;
```

This can be combined with the `ADD` command in a single statement, like :

```
ALTER TABLE `groups`
    DROP COLUMN `forum_enabled`,
    ADD COLUMN `forum_enabled`  enum('0','1') ...
;
```

It is also possible to dynamically check if a column exists, then drop it if neede, like :

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE 
        table_name = 'groups' 
        AND column_name = 'forum_enabled'
        AND table_schema = DATABASE()
) THEN
    ALTER TABLE `groups` 
    DROP COLUMN `forum_enabled`;
END IF;
```